# Changing the color of a Push Button in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, button, stylesheet, qt-creator

How do I change a buttons color?
I have found ways to do it by writing

```
button->setStyleSheet("* { background-color: rgb(255,125,100) }");
```

in Ui_Window.h

But everytime I qmake, the Ui_Window.h gets remade and I lose my colors.

Does anyone know how to permanently keep the colors of the button? I am working with QT Creator. If someone could direct me =D

Thanks so much!

Comment: have a look to my answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395231

Comment: Jeromes link is the correct solution. You shouldn't touch the ui_window.h file as that is automatically generated when you use the Qt Designer. It will be overwritten so any changes you add will disappear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correctly set the color of a QPushButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395231/how-to-correctly-set-the-color-of-a-qpushbutton)

Answer (score 6):

- Easiest way would be to use a style sheet on the button:

  ```
  backgroundColourButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Aero, take into account that you MUST not modify Ui_Window.h file since it is **generated by Qt Designer**. So, every time you recompile the .ui file, this header file will be overwriten. As I see, you are using Qt Designer to add buttons to the layout. In this case, you can right click on a widget (or in the main dialog) in Qt Designer and click then in 'Change layout...'. On there, you can do something like:

```
QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(255,125,100);
}
```

for all buttons, or for an specific button:

```
#nameOfTheButton {
    background-color: rgb(255,125,100);
}
```

Tell me if this works for you. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you use your form only in one class, you may add your expression there, after calling to `ui->setupUi()` in it.
Or even add stylesheet directly to form, look for property 'StyleSheet' in properties view of Qt designer.