# How to correctly set the color of a QPushButton?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

I can successfully change the color of a `QPushButton` using `setStyleSheet`, but because I'm using Qt Creator to make the GUI, every time I run `qmake` and make, the calls to `setStyleSheet` disappear.

Changing the palette of the button doesn't change its color either.

What's the best way to change to color of the button without having to manually change my `ui_window.h` file every time I qmake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using style sheets is the right way to do, no matter you're using *Qt Creator* or not.

From what you are describing, it seems you are writing yourself some code into the `ui_window.h`, which is the **wrong** way to set the stylesheet.

You can set it in the constructor of your `window` class, or set it from the GUI editor (*Qt Designer*) :

- double-click on your `window.ui` in the project tree displayed by *Qt Creator*.
- select your `QPushButton` in the GUI editor.
- locate the `styleSheet` property in the properties editor.
- click on the three dots (`...`) : this will bring a stylesheet editor.

If you set the stylesheet with the stylesheet editor, nothing will disappear each time you are rebuilding your app.